# Is there a way to retrieve an image from the NSURLCache?

Tags: image, caching, resources, uiwebview, nsurlcache

When a UIWebView loads a request the normal way it will most likely cache it, including it's images. I would like people to select the images to store in their Camera Roll.

At this point I can detect the URL of the image the user has tapped on within the UIWebView. My ignorant answer would be to download the image with NSURLConnection, but that feels wrong as the image has already been downloaded and probably been stored in the Cache already. So is there a way to check if the image has already been cached and get it from their instead of downloading the image twice?

I tried to get a NSCachedURLResponse like so:

```
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Collage_of_Six_Cats-02.jpg/250px-Collage_of_Six_Cats-02.jpg"]];
    NSCachedURLResponse *response = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

But the 'response' is constantly nil, does that just imply it does not get cached?

---

Edit:

When using the request in :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

It does return a valid response. However if I use the same URL in the request I create myself it returns nil again I am confused.

Comment: I don't know what is causing your problem but take into account using library called SDUrlCache ( https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache ) . Maybe your bug is connected with fact that iOS is using only in-memory cache...

Answer (score 2):

NSURLCache behaviour depends on the request's cache policy, cache configuration
and cache response from the server. 
You can do the following things to make cache work appropriately. 

1)
You have to make sure that you are initialising NSURLCache before using it like this.

[NSURLCache sharedURLCache];

2) You can manually set the request's cache policy which you are loading from the webview
request.cachePolicy = NSURLCacheStorageAllowed;